# TypeError: Cannot destructure property `name` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: node.js, express.js, jest

Estou usando jest junto com supertest para testar os endpoints da minha aplicação.
Os testes com as requisições get estão funcionando, porém o teste com a requisição post esta dando erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**clientRoutes.test.js**

```
const supertest = require('supertest')
const clientRoutes = require('../Routes/clientRoutes');
const db = require('../database_connection');

describe('Test the clients path', () => {
test('should post client', async () => {

        const { rows } = await db.query("SELECT * FROM client WHERE name = 'baz'")
        console.log(rows[0]);
        const res = await supertest(clientRoutes)
            .post('/client')
            .send({ name: 'baz', password: 333333 })
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        expect(res.body).toEqual(rows[0])
    });
})
```

**clientRoutes.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const clientController = require('../controllers/clientController');

const routes = express()

...
routes.post('/client', clientController.create)
...

module.exports = routes;
```

**clientController.js**

```
const db = require('../database_connection');
module.exports = {

    ...

    async create(req, res) {
        let { name, password } = req.body
        password += crypto.randomBytes(4).toString('HEX')

        const { rows } = await db.query('INSERT INTO carrinho_de_compras.client VALUES ($1, $2)')
        res.send(rows[0])
    }

   ...          
}
```

Comment: `let { name, password } = JSON.parse(req.body);`

Comment: deu certo, obrigado ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa no seu arquivo que você levanta a API FAKE com o supertest, colocar isto. Porque assim o seu servidor está apto a receber requisições com o formato de JSON.
O formato que o colega acima colocou usando `JSON.parse(req.body)` está correto também, porém é mais fácil fazer da forma que coloquei, porque senão toda vez que você for fazer um `POST` precisará colocar `JSON.parse()`.

```
const routes = express();

routes.use(express.json());
```